# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when redirecting subpage

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I've been doing 301 redirects for all my subpages on my website (from subpage.example.com to example.com/subpage) and they all worked out except for one page. I used this code which worked on the other subpages.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/subpage$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://example.com/subpage [L,QSA,R=301]
```

However, this code redirects this specific subpage from subpage.example.com to example.com/subpage/, which makes the page not have any styling elements and also added an extra "/" in the URL. If I remove the extra "/" in the URL, I get redirected to the correct page with the correct styling, so I suspect it's the extra "/" that's causing the problem.

The code is in a .htaccess file which is in the subpage folder in my FTP (FileZilla) remote site. I did the exact same steps for all subpages and only one is not working.

Can anyone help me out with this problem? I hope I've explained so you understand

When I inspected the subpage, this error comes up "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'  script.js:1

If I click on script.js:1 the message says I have  in the style.css file and claims it's wrong. I then open the style.css file on my VS Code but can't see  anywhere in that file.

Comment: script.js is probably non-existent. Apache can't find it and outputs a 404 page, which starts with a < tag, as it's HTML.